# answer incoming call using asterisk manager api

Tags: java, asteriskami, incoming-call

I am writing Java program to handle call in asterisk using Manager API.

I am able to know the incoming call through program. Now, I need to answer the incoming call. I dont want to do it from AGI or through dialplan but from Manager api action (not from ami command). 
Any hints, suggestion or complete answer is hepful.

Comment: Any suggestion or what can be done to get the answer ? HELP ..

Answer (score -1):

It's 6 months late, and I don't have a solution but this may give you an idea.

```
public void service(AgiRequest request, AgiChannel channel) throws AgiException {
    answer();
    exec("Playback", "tt-monkeys"); 
    hangup();
}
```

I don't know what is AgiRequest, how can you get the calling channel and how to call this function in your code (it would help me too if I knew). But with that function I believe you can answer.